# regexMatcher in String Manipulation KNIME

Tags: string, knime

I'm trying to use regexMatcher from String Manipulation in KNIME but it doesn't work. I'm writing the following:
regexMatcher($Document$,"/\w")
when I want to extract all sentences that have /s or /p or w/p or /200. However even though I have such cases in my table nothing is retrieved. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Try `regexMatcher($Document$,"/\\w") = "TRUE"`

Comment: I have updated my question. I have tried to use your suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: Try `"^\\w*/\\w+$"`

Comment: It doesn't work too. Looks like this functionality not working at all. Can it be the case?

Comment: If you can find any documentation or source code, we could check. BTW, from what I know, the regex flavor is the same as Java.

Comment: The point is that it works but I get as a result that everything is false and nothing matches the regular expression. Maybe you are familiar with other way of doing the same. I just have to filter these type of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following:

```
|Document      |isOK |other|strict|
|--------------|-----|-----|------|
|Some /p with q|True |False|False |
|/200          |True |True |False |
|/p            |True |True |True  |
|/s            |True |True |True  |
|w/p           |True |False|False |
|no slash      |False|False|False |
```

For the expressions:

- **isOK: `regexMatcher($Document$, ".*?/\\w.*")` (I guess this is what you are after.)**
- other: `regexMatcher($Document$, "/\\w.*")`
- strict: `regexMatcher($Document$, "/\\w")`

(Document contains no content after the last visible character.)

The problem you might run into is the escaping for the string manipulator node and the semantics of `regexMatcher`.

The String literal within there is just a Java String, so you have to escape the `\` (and some other characters), so it becomes `\\`.

The semantics of `regexMatcher` is to match the whole String, so you have to add `.*?` (non-greedy match anything) before the value you are looking for and `.*` (greedy match anything) after the expression you are looking for.
(Obviously if I misunderstood your question, the semantics is probably already is what you want.)

BTW: in case you want to filter, you should check the [Rule-based Row Filter](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.base.node.rules.engine.RuleEngineFilterNodeFactory.html) node as it offers an option to directly filter by regex. It uses a different escaping rule (for the isOK option):

- `$Document$  MATCHES ".*?/\w.*" => TRUE` (escaping is not allowed within quotes)
- `$Document$  MATCHES /.*?\/\\w.*/ => TRUE` (escaping is allowed within slashes (and `/`, `\` are need to be escaped, but `"` is not required))

[image: Example workflow]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for